# How can i run function when the checkout page is opened?

Tags: event-observer, magento-1

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and i am working on a custom extension.

My question is:
How can i run custom php function when the checkout page is opened?

I know i have to mess around with the events of the extension config file but i am not exactly sure how i can point the function in the observer which i want to run when the checkout page is opened.

Here is events part of my config:

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>checkitemsincartv</method>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>               
        <controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>
            <observers>
                <hss_save_order_onepage>
                    <class>paypal/observer</class>
                    <method>setResponseAfterSaveOrder</method>
                </hss_save_order_onepage>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder>
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
            <custom_ads>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>checkitemsincartv</method>
            </custom_ads>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>                 
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <newsletter_order_place_after>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>newsletter</method>
                </newsletter_order_place_after>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>

         <checkout_submit_all_after>
            <observers>
                <opc_checkout_submit_all_after>
                    <class>opc/observer</class>
                    <method>applyComment</method>
                </opc_checkout_submit_all_after>
            </observers>
        </checkout_submit_all_after>

    </events>
```

And in the observer i have added this:

```
public function checkitemsincartv($observer)
{
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setItemsInCart("Works");
    $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    Mage::log($data->debug(), null, "order.log", true);
}
```

But it seems to be not working.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: are you want order object at  event?

Comment: The important this is this function to run before the items are cleared and the order is placed. For that reason i asked how this function can be runned when the checkout page is opened. If other method will do the trick it's ok. Thanks for the help man!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that you have default **magento onepage checkout**.

So you event should be

```
controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_index
```

**Instead of**

```
controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveOrder
```

### EDit:

As you have using IWD extension ,then your event may be:

```
controller_action_postdispatch_opc_index_index
```

Comment: I do not use the default checkout page. I use the onepage checkout extension by IWD.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: let me check .. it may be different

Comment: Is it possible ?

Comment: I have updated the config.xml in my question but still it seems that this function is not called...

Comment: config.xml do not define properly

Comment: have your problem resovled

Comment: No, i have found another solution. It was not the resolving answer but i marked it as a gratfull of your help.